# overflow sobrepondo padding

Tags: css, css3

Bom tenho uma div onde uso o padding e o overflow porem quando o overflow é ativado e aparece a barra de rolagem o texto passa por cima da area do padding, exite uma maneira de fazer com que o overflow comece a partir da area inicial do padding?

http://jsfiddle.net/thpojv5p

visualização na pratica, onde esta escrito chat chat chat ... ponha o mouse e role para baixo e veja que as palavras vao sobrepor a posicao inicial do padding
http://yugioh.site/layout.html

OBS: Gostaria de uma solução que não fosse criar uma nova div(afim de reduzir o codigo)

Comment: http://yugioh.site/layout.html acesse e veja onde esta escrito chat, role para baixo o texto e veja que as palavras vao entrar em cima da imagem

Answer (score 2):

Editei o seu fiddle mas como nunca mexi nele não sei se vai aparecer pra vc a alteração que fiz . 
[aqui o link](http://jsfiddle.net/thpojv5p/1/)

O que faria o seguinte pra resolver seu problema :

Colocaria as mensagens em uma segunda div interna , dei o id dela de mensagens:

```
<div id="chat">
<div id="mensagens">

  chat
  <br>chat
  <br>chat
  <br>chat
  <br>chat
  <br>chat
  <br>chat
  <br>chat
  <br>chat
  <br>chat
  <br>chat
  <br>chat
  <br>chat
  <br>chat
  <br>chat
  <br>chat
  <br>chat
  <br>chat
  <br>chat
  <br>chat
  <br>chat
  <br>chat
  <br>chat
  <br>chat
  <br>chat
  <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

e no css ajustaria a distancia com um margin , o css ficou assim

```
#chat {
  height: 39vh;
  width: 27.5vw;
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 55vh;
  left: 21vw;
  background-image: url("http://pre11.deviantart.net/b65d/th/pre/i/2005/076/5/e/frame_by_anilestock.jpg");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  -margin:auto;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#mensagens
{
  margin-left:30px;
  margin-top:20px;
  width:120px;
  height:139px;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: ha sim. isso funciona sim ja ate fiz, porem, gostaria de saber se é possivel fazer isso sem que seja criando uma nova div